# How to change the size and font of a text in aTabItem (TabLayout)?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-tablayout

I created `TabLayout` with 3 items(the item in the middle is not an icon but a text).

How can I change the size of the text and his font?

```
<android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
    android:id="@+id/tabs"
    app:tabTextColor="#777777"
    app:tabIndicatorColor="@color/hellrot"
    app:tabSelectedTextColor="@color/hellrot"
    app:tabIconTint="@color/your_color_selector"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>

<android.support.design.widget.TabItem
    android:id="@+id/tabItem"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_wc_black_24dp" />

<android.support.design.widget.TabItem
    android:id="@+id/tabItem2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Main"
/>

<android.support.design.widget.TabItem
    android:id="@+id/tabItem3"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_tag_faces_black_24dp" 
/>

</android.support.design.widget.TabLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Write these below codes in styles.xml

Example:

```
<style name="MyTabItem" parent="TextAppearance.AppCompat.Button">
    <item name="android:textSize">18sp</item>
</style>
```

And in your TabItem, set the style like below.

```
<android.support.design.widget. TabItem
 style="@style/MyTabItem"
 android:layout_width="width"
 android:layout_height="height"/>
```